# Can't change size element of palette

Tags: java, android

I have `surfaceView` in `fragment_main.xml`, it is set to 50dp width and 50dp height.
this `fragment_main.xml` is included in `framelayout` in `content_main.xml` and this is included in `activity_main.xml`.

And when i run this app, surface view is on entire of screen, it is not dependend of width and height. This surface look that same with 500dp/500dp and 20dp/20dp, It takes the entire screen all the time

**Question:**
I just want to make this layout very small and at the bottom of the screen, how can I do that? I tried changing the width and height, but nothing changed.

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xx.xxx.testv4.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<FrameLayout

android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="xx.xxx.testv4.MainActivityFragment"
        >

        <view
            android:id="@+id/cView"
            class="xx.xxx.testv4.mySurfaceView"
            id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"


 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.93"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```